# How to wrap price in span regexp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, price

I'm trying to wrap the price of an item in a span. Right now the RegExp wraps the numbers but not the $ (dollar sign). I need a regex that wraps the entire price.

```
HTML
<fieldset>
  <label>
   <input>Thing $4.99</input>
  </label>
</fieldset>

JQUERY
    var rxp = new RegExp("([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)", "gm");
      $( "fieldset label" ).each(function() {                
        var $this = $(this);
        var content = $this.html();
        console.log($(this).html());
        $this.html(content.replace(rxp, "<span>$1</span>"));
      });
```

Comment: Add a dollar sign by escaping it `(\$[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct way to do it. `html()` method will return you html markup, but changing it will not change the DOM. Instead you should empty your parent and append new span in it. Also you are using `input` tag in a wrong way, it can't have children, you should set value to `value` attr:

```
// HTML
<fieldset>
  <label>
   <input value="Thing $4.99" />
  </label>
</fieldset>

// JavaScript
var priceRegExp = /^.*(\$[0-9](\.[0-9]{2})?).*$/;
$("fieldset label").each(function() {                
  var $this = $(this);
  var inputVal = $this.children('input').prop('value');
  var price = priceRegExp.exec(inputVal)[1];
  $this.empty().append('span').text(price);
});
```

Comment: gotcha, sadly i dont have control over HTML output its from a shopify plugin...this is close. it empties the input though, which isnt what i want to, but rather move the price outside in another span... think i can take it from here ! thx